# OWL API loading ontology with comments

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

With OWL API I have a problem of loading ontology file with comments (in functional-style syntax). If the ontology has no comments - there is no problem with loading the ontology. Important: I cannot change or modify the input ontology. The question is how to fix it.

The example of comments that cause the problem (all starts with "#"):

```
# Object Property: <http://www.semanticweb.org/asus/ontologies/2014/10/untitled-ontology-122#has_H_F_F_H> (<http://www.semanticweb.org/asus/ontologies/2014/10/untitled-ontology-122#has_H_F_F_H>)
```

Such comments are automatically added by e.g. Protege tool.

The problem occures in the fourth line:

```
      OWLOntologyManager manager=OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(); 
      OWLDataFactory dataFactory=manager.getOWLDataFactory();
      File inputDomainOntologyFile = new File(pathToDomainOntology);
      OWLOntology domainOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(inputDomainOntologyFile);
```

And results in:

```
UnparsableOntologyException
```

Comment: Are you using the Manchester syntax for OWL 2 ?

Comment: Yes and no, I am checking all available parsers. Among them there is also Manchester but of course I am checking the functional-style as well

Comment: Can you make a complete, functional example and post it on GitHub?

Comment: I would not be easy, but the error occurs in this line only - the ontology does not parse. The rest of the code is irrelevant.

Comment: I added 3 lines before, the rest of the code does not influence the input ontology

Comment: What is wrong with the question so that someone removed me the point?!

Comment: I don't get the problem, why can't you edit the ontology? I mean, you have access to it somehow. Moreover, you said it was created with Protege, this also makes me assume you have access to it. Note, Protege uses OWL API under the hood, I'd assume it works. Which version of Protege do you use? And which OWL API version in your code?

Comment: Lack of information is the probable cause of downvote.